# Finding issue with col-md and col-sm in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My agenda is to show an **image** and **Details** side by side in laptop and in responsive show them individually.. It works in non-responsive page showing the details side by side with col-md-6, but the code doesnt accept col-sm-12 for showing the details induvidually in responsive state

```
<section id="about-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0">
        <img class="col-img" src="reference/about-us/choice.jpg" alt="color choices">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0">
        <div class="col-details">
          <div class="col-details-title">
            ABOUT US
          </div>
          <div class="col-details-subtext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius, itaque odio vel fugiat sit minima illum doloremque qui esse. Minima veniam soluta numquam mollitia vel aspernatur, nobis maxime in!
            <br>
            <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis amet, alias nam! Cooris doloremque tempora sed facilis eveniet, quis voluptas quaerat accusamus tenetur, laborum debitis consequuntur ad facere beatae. Enim.
          </div>
          <div>
            <button style="margin-left: 250px; margin-top: 50px;">View More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: which screen size are you targeting with `col-sm`

Comment: You declare sm as `col-sm-12` you should change to `col-sm-6`

Comment: Please check the code now. i have given it col-sm-12

Comment: @AryanTwanju screen size of 320px .targeting mobile device withe col-sm

Comment: @rajiv Which div is not responsive . Image div , details div or both?

Comment: if you are targeting screen size of 320px you should go with `col-xs-6` instead of `col-sm-6`, because you seem to be using bootstrap4.

Comment: @ToujouAya: Both. they are showing side by side in responsive state. But i am trying to show them individually i.e image takes the entire screen and next it shows the details..(Down by down)

Comment: @AryanTwanju: Tried with col-xs-12 too.. still shows it side by side

Comment: @rajiv if you target with screen size 320px you should change to `col-12` because this is Class prefix for extra small screen. Check it here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I got it working had missed out the meta tag in header. Sorry guys... But thanks for the additional info.. Cheers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All i have Solved this issue..  had MISSED OUT WITH THE META TAG IN HEADER

Answer (score 1):

**Use `img-fluid` to image(see Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/gpLyvr5w/6/)**

Learn here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="about-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" alt="color choices">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0">
        <div class="col-details">
          <div class="col-details-title">
            ABOUT US
          </div>
          <div class="col-details-subtext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius, itaque odio vel fugiat sit minima illum doloremque qui esse. Minima veniam soluta numquam mollitia vel aspernatur, nobis maxime in!
            <br>
            <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis amet, alias nam! Cooris doloremque tempora sed facilis eveniet, quis voluptas quaerat accusamus tenetur, laborum debitis consequuntur ad facere beatae. Enim.
          </div>
          <div>
            <button style="margin-left: 250px; margin-top: 50px;">View More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: not exactly... But this helps in my code too.. Had missed the meta tag... Beginner mistake.

Answer (score 1):

well the code `class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0"` means that at screen ≥576px the element should take full width (aka width:100%) of available width but if the screen is ≥768px then the element should take half the available width (aka width:50%).

So if you need your div containing image and div with details to be side by side on screens ≥768px (usually tablets in portrait mode) then simply use `col-md-6` you don't need to specify `col-sm-12` as by default div elements are block level elements and take full width of available space.

Also you don't need `padding-0` class you can use Bootstrap 4's spacing classes such as p-0, p-1, p-3, pt-1, py-3 etc. to remove or add padding so your final classes should look like this:

`class="col-md-6 p-0"`

Answer (score 0):

You Need to give the extra class in first col-md-6 i have given class name res and write a media query for that like these

```
    <style>
         @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
         {
          .res{
                min-width:100%;
           }
         }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="about-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0 res">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" alt="color choices">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 padding-0">
        <div class="col-details">
          <div class="col-details-title">
            ABOUT US
          </div>
          <div class="col-details-subtext">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime eius, itaque odio vel fugiat sit minima illum doloremque qui esse. Minima veniam soluta numquam mollitia vel aspernatur, nobis maxime in!
            <br>
            <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis amet, alias nam! Cooris doloremque tempora sed facilis eveniet, quis voluptas quaerat accusamus tenetur, laborum debitis consequuntur ad facere beatae. Enim.
          </div>
          <div>
            <button style="margin-left: 250px; margin-top: 50px;">View More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```